# How to implement polymorphism in spring boot properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to provide initialization using Spring boot.
But input can be initialised using polymorphism. How can I take care of polymorphism(in input application.yml file) while initialising using spring boot

I have class

```
interface Parent {
}

class C1 implements Parent {
   int c1;
}

class C2 implements Parent {
   String c2;
}

class A {
    Parent p;
    public void setP(Parent p) {
       this.p = p;
    }
}

class SpringBootExamples {
   @Autowired
   public A a;
}
```

Here how should we define application.yml OR spring boot will intelligently identify C1 or C2?

```
a:
 p:
   c1: 123
```

OR

```
a:
  p:
    c2: strvalue
```